# How to implement Gaussian Naive Bayes in two training sets

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, seaborn

how am I supposed to implement Gaussian Naive Bayes, in two training sets.

I need:
Create a training set by selecting the rows with id <= 160
Train a Gaussian Naive-Bayes classifier as we saw in class to determine if a campaign will be successful, given the amounts used in each marketing channel
Calculate the fraction of the training set that is correctly classified.

and:
Create a test set by selecting the rows with id> 160
Evaluate the performance of the classifier as follows:
What percentage of the test set was classified
correctly (correct answers on the total)? It is desirable that this number reaches at least 80%
What is the ratio of false positives to false negatives?

Successful marketing campaign:

```
successful_marketing_campaign = (dataset['sales'] > 15) | (dataset['total_invested'] < 20)
```

And my code:

```
X = dataset.iloc[:, [0, 3]].values.astype('int')
y = dataset.iloc[:, [4]].values.astype('int')

X_train = dataset.iloc[0:160, [0, 3]].values.astype('int')
y_train = dataset.iloc[0:160, 4].values.astype('int')

X_test = dataset.iloc[160:, [0, 3]].values.astype('int')
y_test = dataset.iloc[160:, 4].values.astype('int')

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
print(matrix)
```

Comment: so, what is the question?

Comment: How to implement two training sets?

Comment: it does not make it more clear. Can you rephrase?